# Confirmation of organoid's character with the respective organ

Tags: stem-cells

How can we verify that the Organoid formed from culturing stem cells shows the exact characteristics of the organ it is developed for?

Answer (score 1):

Verification of organoids is done by detecting the cellular proteins for particular tissue type using [Immunofluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immunofluorescence).

For verifying intestinal organoid, apical membrane markers  (villin or alkaline phosphatase) and basolateral markers (E-cadhehrin) are detected by immunofluorescence. Transporters present in intestinal membranes are also displayed on organoids.  The peptide transporter PEPT1 and the glucose transporter SGLT1 are located on apical membrane, and the glucose transporter GLUT2 is present on basolateral membrane. So, these proteins can also be used as markers for verifying intestinal cells.

Via:

- https://www.nature.com/articles/srep16831
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19329995